# how to turn a text file into a 2D array split by the prompt and hint using this symbol '-'?

Tags: c#

[image: my text file]

so ideally, what i'm aiming for is to put the prompts and hints into a 2D array, split with the indicator '-', any and all advice on it would be helpful thanks!

Comment: A combination of `File.ReadAllLines()` and `string.Split()` perhaps?  What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(); string[][] x = new string[lines.length][2]; then loop through lines, split these . set the values of x array

Comment: thanks, i have tried streamreader and .split and it was only reading the first line, but if i use okay so file.readalllines will give me every line but then how to put them out one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read it with File.ReadAllLines and the split all rows

```
        var rows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\ks1.txt");
        string[,] d2A = new string[rows.Length, 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
        {
            var row = rows[i].Split(new string[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            d2A[i, 0] = row[0];
            d2A[i, 1] = row[1];
        }
```